# Unable to link ycm_core.dll when compiling YCM

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, cygwin

i am trying to compile the YouCompleteMe (YCM) plugin on cygwin on windows 10, and every time the compiler fails when linking the ycm_core.dll shared library. I will paste my output in this post, which is a very long output, so to summarize, most of the logs are "reference to undefined 'X'" where X is some boost.python related function.

I have already tried these [instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide-for-Unix%E2%80%90like-Environments), in which the specified patch does not exist any more, so i used this [patch](https://gist.github.com/fatso83/9e48064296c337fd2978) but was unable to install it with the patch command (got "hunk failed" every time).

Thank you to anyone that can help.

The following is my output. Note that the post is limited to 30000 characters and my output is over 120000 characters long, so my entire output did not fit in this post. however, it was more or less the same all the way down (more undefined references).

```
$ ./install.py
Searching Python 2.7 libraries...
Found Python library: /usr/bin/python2.7
Found Python headers folder: /usr/include/python2.7
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.13", minimum required is "2.6")
NOT using libclang, no semantic completion for C/C++/ObjC will be available
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/ycm_build_Gt3KX6
[67/67] Linking CXX shared library /home/gazran/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.dll
FAILED: /home/gazran/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.dll ycm/libycm_core.dll.a
: && /usr/bin/c++.exe  -O3 -DNDEBUG    -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o /home/gazran/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_core.dll -Wl,--out-implib,ycm/libycm_core.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Candidate.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/CandidateRepository.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierDatabase.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierUtils.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/LetterNode.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/LetterNodeListMap.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Result.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/Utils.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/versioning.cpp.o ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o  BoostParts/libBoostParts.a /usr/bin/python2.7 -lrt && :
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x28): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x5a): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x5a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x92): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0xc3): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0xc3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x260): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x3df): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x3df): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x505): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x505): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x5ff): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x5ff): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x7a3): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x7a3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x873): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x873): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0x4f): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/IdentifierCompleter.cpp.o:IdentifierCompleter.cpp:(.text.startup+0x16): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x28f): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x425): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x591): undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x15bc): undefined reference to `PyObject_Size'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x15c6): undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x15d8): undefined reference to `PyObject_Size'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x15e0): undefined reference to `PyErr_Occurred'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x16db): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x17e3): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x1841): undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x1941): undefined reference to `PyLong_FromUnsignedLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x1b55): undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x1c84): undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text+0x1fbb): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/PythonSupport.cpp.o:PythonSupport.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `PyEval_InitThreads'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text+0xb43): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvP7_objectENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2IvS6_EEEEEclES6_S6_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvP7_objectENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2IvS6_EEEEEclES6_S6_]+0x11): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKNS0_4listEEEE10get_pytypeEv[_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKNS0_4listEEEE10get_pytypeEv]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKbEEE10get_pytypeEv[_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKbEEE10get_pytypeEv]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyBool_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKmEEE10get_pytypeEv[_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKmEEE10get_pytypeEv]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyInt_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKSsEEE10get_pytypeEv[_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKSsEEE10get_pytypeEv]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyString_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKiEEE10get_pytypeEv[_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRKiEEE10get_pytypeEv]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyInt_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRSsEEE10get_pytypeEv[_ZN5boost6python6detail21converter_target_typeINS0_15to_python_valueIRSsEEE10get_pytypeEv]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp_PyString_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFbvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IbEEEEEclEP7_objectSE_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFbvENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IbEEEEEclEP7_objectSE_]+0xf): undefined reference to `PyBool_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonINS0_7objects14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEEENS_10shared_ptrEE11convertibleEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonINS0_7objects14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEEENS_10shared_ptrEE11convertibleEP7_object]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonINS0_7objects14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEEESt10shared_ptrE11convertibleEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonINS0_7objects14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEEESt10shared_ptrE11convertibleEP7_object]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonIN13YouCompleteMe19IdentifierCompleterENS_10shared_ptrEE11convertibleEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonIN13YouCompleteMe19IdentifierCompleterENS_10shared_ptrEE11convertibleEP7_object]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonIN13YouCompleteMe19IdentifierCompleterESt10shared_ptrE11convertibleEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonIN13YouCompleteMe19IdentifierCompleterESt10shared_ptrE11convertibleEP7_object]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS_10shared_ptrEE11convertibleEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS_10shared_ptrEE11convertibleEP7_object]+0x3): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonISt6vectorISsSaISsEESt10shared_ptrE11convertibleEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python9converter22shared_ptr_from_pythonISt6vectorISsSaISsEESt10shared_ptrE11convertibleEP7_object]+0x3): more undefined references to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct' follow
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFivENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IiEEEEEclEP7_objectSE_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFivENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector1IiEEEEEclEP7_objectSE_]+0xf): undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvRSt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_3api6objectEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector3IvS8_SA_EEEEEclEP7_objectSK_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvRSt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_3api6objectEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector3IvS8_SA_EEEEEclEP7_objectSK_]+0x52): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFbRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP7_objectENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector3IbS8_SA_EEEEEclESA_SA_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFbRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP7_objectENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector3IbS8_SA_EEEEEclESA_SA_]+0x35): undefined reference to `PyBool_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP7_objectENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector3IvS8_SA_EEEEEclESA_SA_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP7_objectENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector3IvS8_SA_EEEEEclESA_SA_]+0x2e): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP7_objectSA_ENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector4IvS8_SA_SA_EEEEEclESA_SA_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFvRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEP7_objectSA_ENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector4IvS8_SA_SA_EEEEEclESA_SA_]+0x32): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFmRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2ImS8_EEEEEclEP7_objectSI_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFmRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2ImS8_EEEEEclEP7_objectSI_]+0x31): undefined reference to `PyInt_FromLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFmRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2ImS8_EEEEEclEP7_objectSI_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFmRSt6vectorISsSaISsEEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2ImS8_EEEEEclEP7_objectSI_]+0x3b): undefined reference to `PyLong_FromUnsignedLong'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter21as_to_python_functionINS0_7objects14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEEENS3_18class_cref_wrapperISG_NS3_13make_instanceISG_NS3_12value_holderISG_EEEEEEE7convertEPKv[_ZN5boost6python9converter21as_to_python_functionINS0_7objects14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEEENS3_18class_cref_wrapperISG_NS3_13make_instanceISG_NS3_12value_holderISG_EEEEEEE7convertEPKv]+0x84): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerINS1_14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEE4nextES9_NS_3mpl7vector2IRSsRSH_EEEEEclEP7_objectSR_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerINS1_14iterator_rangeINS0_19return_value_policyINS0_15return_by_valueENS0_21default_call_policiesEEEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEE4nextES9_NS_3mpl7vector2IRSsRSH_EEEEEclEP7_objectSR_]+0x37): undefined reference to `PyString_FromStringAndSize'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFSsRKNS0_3api6objectEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2ISsS8_EEEEEclEP7_objectSI_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFSsRKNS0_3api6objectEENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector2ISsS8_EEEEEclEP7_objectSI_]+0x2d): undefined reference to `PyString_FromStringAndSize'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x13): undefined reference to `__imp_PySlice_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x141): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x150): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x173): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x180): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x18f): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x382): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_TypeError'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE16base_delete_itemERS4_P7_object]+0x391): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_mENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector5IS5_S7_S9_S9_mEEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_mENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector5IS5_S7_S9_S9_mEEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_mENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector5IS5_S7_S9_S9_mEEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_mENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector5IS5_S7_S9_S9_mEEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_]+0x2a): undefined reference to `PyObject_IsInstance'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_ENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector4IS5_S7_S9_S9_EEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_ENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector4IS5_S7_S9_S9_EEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_]+0x1c): undefined reference to `__imp_PyList_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_ENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector4IS5_S7_S9_S9_EEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_[_ZN5boost6python7objects23caller_py_function_implINS0_6detail6callerIPFNS0_4listERKS5_RKSsS9_ENS0_21default_call_policiesENS_3mpl7vector4IS5_S7_S9_S9_EEEEEclEP7_objectSJ_]+0x2a): undefined reference to `PyObject_IsInstance'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python9converter21as_to_python_functionISt10shared_ptrISt6vectorISsSaISsEEENS0_7objects19class_value_wrapperIS7_NS8_17make_ptr_instanceIS6_NS8_14pointer_holderIS7_S6_EEEEEEE7convertEPKv[_ZN5boost6python9converter21as_to_python_functionISt10shared_ptrISt6vectorISsSaISsEEENS0_7objects19class_value_wrapperIS7_NS8_17make_ptr_instanceIS6_NS8_14pointer_holderIS7_S6_EEEEEEE7convertEPKv]+0x86): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0x13): undefined reference to `__imp_PySlice_Type'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0xc3): undefined reference to `PyString_FromStringAndSize'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0x10d): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0x11c): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0x143): undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0x154): undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_IndexError'
ycm/CMakeFiles/ycm_core.dir/ycm_core.cpp.o:ycm_core.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object[_ZN5boost6python14indexing_suiteISt6vectorISsSaISsEENS0_6detail29final_vector_derived_policiesIS4_Lb0EEELb0ELb0ESsmSsE13base_get_itemENS0_14back_referenceIRS4_EEP7_object]+0x163): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
```

Comment: You should ask directly to the maintainers of the plugin via its [issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues) you will get more people working on this plugin and likely to know a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@statox](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox), I went to check out this [issue tracker](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues). This in turn led me to YouCompleteMe's CONTRIBUTIND.md document which then sent me to gitter where there is a community chat room for questions about many topics, including YCM.

The build was getting the python library from /usr/bin/python2.7 instead of /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dll.a. to fix this, go to ~/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/build.py and change the FindPythonLibraries() function to the following:

```
def FindPythonLibraries():
    return["/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dll.a", "/usr/include/python2.7"]
```